# Kibana 4.3: How do load visualization only after a filter is applied?

Tags: kibana-4

[Background]

> I have a dashboard which logs performance of my application for
>   multiple versions.

[Query]

> Need to load a specific visualization(say line graph) only when a
>   filter of 'version:1.1' is applied.

[Additional Info]

The reason behind this is when no version is selected, it loads all the samples of all the version which is messy and the data is unreadable.

I cannot add that as a filter before hand because I don't know which version the user would want to analyse.

Also, I want to avoid another hyperlink which re-directs to a new page.[If this is possible, please share as I am not sure, how would I force user to select app version before moving to that page]

P.S.: Please let me know if I am not making sense here.

Comment: Do you need to have multiple visualisations based on versions? Do you need to re-create such scenario for multiple versions?

Comment: @YuvrajGupta- Yes. I do have multiple visualizations based on versions.
and yes, i would need to re-create such scenario for multiple version.
Say at time version 1.1 can be selected and at other time 1.2 can be selected, now i need to populate another visualization only after one of the filter is applied

Comment: I can suggest you to create multiple dashboards for each version, i.e. if you have v1.0, v1.1, v1.2 then create 3 dashboards wherein each dashboard will have a filter of v1.0, v1.1 & v1.2 respectively. We can then create a markdown and mention versions to view for dashboards.

I know this is not a good approach as it would require lots of re-work (if visualizations are same across each version) but currently I am unable to think of something else which you might use to solve ur use-case.

Do let me know if it fits your scenario, will write a detailed answer on how to do it.

Comment: Not an option. The objective is to study trend of multiple versions at the same time and identify if there is a spike in one of it. If yes, then analyse the detail trend.

Comment: Why don't you create visualizations in such a way that it covers all the versions. For example - You are creating a line chart and you need it for v1.0, v1.1, v1.2. For this create a line chart & add filters in it such as version:v1.0, version:v1.1, version:v1.2. It will give you details for each version in a single visualization which you can later add to the dashboard. Does this situation help you in your use-case?